# How to evaluate clustering algorithm in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

My data has 61 rows and 56 columns.
I have tested several clustering algorithms and i will later evaluate them, but I found some problems. I just succeed to apply the silhouette coefficient.
I have performed K means clustering using this code:

```
kmean = KMeans(n_clusters=6)
kmean.fit(X)
kmean.labels_
#Evaluation
silhouette_score(X,kmean.labels_)
 ==>0.09231070598844496
```

I would like to try more measurements such as :

```
metrics.homogeneity_score,
metrics.completeness_score,
metrics.v_measure_score,
metrics.adjusted_rand_score,
metrics.adjusted_mutual_info_score,
```

I want to evaluate my clustering. And I do not know how. what they mean by `labels_true`, `labels_pred`? how can I use the sklearn evaluations metrics?

Comment: `labels_true` means the actual label and `labels_pred` means what your modeled thinks it is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !
When I want as an example to try the adjusted_rand_score  what are the parameters!

Comment: You can see in the documentation: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.adjusted_rand_score.html, it is same: `adjusted_rand_score(labels_true, labels_pred)`

Comment: In my code is : labels_true = X ,labels_pred=kmean.labels_ ? Thank you for help

Comment: @ab20225 posting code in comments is difficult to read. You should edit your question.

Answer (score 1):

`labels_true`: Ground Truth values/Actual labels

`labels_pred`: Labels predicted using clustering model

For example:

```
labels_pred = clustering_model.predict(model_df.values)
```

All the below metrics needs ground truth, its not internal metric:

```
metrics.homogeneity_score,
metrics.completeness_score,
metrics.v_measure_score,
metrics.adjusted_rand_score,
metrics.adjusted_mutual_info_score,
```

You can try `silhouette_score` or `calinski_harabasz_score` or `davies_bouldin_score` or `dunn_index`